# How to get list of objects from json string asp.net mvc Newtonsoft.json

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I am trying to convert a JSON string into a list of objects but am getting the error

Cannot deserialize the current JSON object into type List because the type requires a JSON array to deserialize correctly.

I retrieve the json and it looks like this

```
     {
    "totalCount": 4,
    "items": [
        {
            "Tarih": "10-10-2019",
            "TP_DK_SAR_A": "1.5538",
            "TP_DK_SAR_S": "1.5566",
            "TP_DK_EUR_A": "6.3974",
            "TP_DK_EUR_S": "6.4089",
            "TP_DK_CHF_A": "5.8504",
            "TP_DK_GBP_A": "7.1119",
            "TP_DK_JPY_A": "5.4183",
            "UNIXTIME": {
                "$numberLong": "1570658400"
            }
        },
        {
            "Tarih": "11-10-2019",
            "TP_DK_SAR_A": "1.5651",
            "TP_DK_SAR_S": "1.568",
            "TP_DK_EUR_A": "6.4694",
            "TP_DK_EUR_S": "6.481",
            "TP_DK_CHF_A": "5.9019",
            "TP_DK_GBP_A": "7.1727",
            "TP_DK_JPY_A": "5.4515",
            "UNIXTIME": {
                "$numberLong": "1570744800"
            }
        },
        {
            "Tarih": "12-10-2019",
            "TP_DK_SAR_A": null,
            "TP_DK_SAR_S": null,
            "TP_DK_EUR_A": null,
            "TP_DK_EUR_S": null,
            "TP_DK_CHF_A": null,
            "TP_DK_GBP_A": null,
            "TP_DK_JPY_A": null,
            "UNIXTIME": {
                "$numberLong": "1570831200"
            }
        },
        {
            "Tarih": "13-10-2019",
            "TP_DK_SAR_A": null,
            "TP_DK_SAR_S": null,
            "TP_DK_EUR_A": null,
            "TP_DK_EUR_S": null,
            "TP_DK_CHF_A": null,
            "TP_DK_GBP_A": null,
            "TP_DK_JPY_A": null,
            "UNIXTIME": {
                "$numberLong": "1570917600"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I solved the problem and used two different methods;

```
1-)
     ExchangeRateGetViewModel CompanyInfoData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExchangeRateGetViewModel>(jsonResultString);

2-)
var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonResultString);
            var h = o.Value<JArray>("items")
                .ToObject<List<ExchangeRateGetListViewModel>>();
```